# How can i make a text box that changes input constantly?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, static

So I want to create a text box "static if possible" that when my user interacts with the story game the text inside changes to accommodate his action. so im guessing i want a pointer to the char variable, but it seems that i cant figure out how to do this... can someone help me please.

im thinking create the static box with a argument that is a pointer, so i can constantly change its address to another string of text. would this work? because at the moment im changing the value of the char string and nothing is happening.

Comment: which GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: So what GUI are you using? Windows, X, Quartz, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the content of a standard Win32 textbox, you simply send the [WM_SETTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632644(VS.85).aspx) message.